# Error with pip install MySQLdb library

Tags: python, python-2.7, mysql-python

In python 2.7.10,
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqldb(from version)
no matching distribution found for mysqldb

**pip install MySQL-python also failed:** Unable to find vcvarsall.bat and many other errors if I am patching solution for this one.

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: yes, Windows versions 7/8/8.1/10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building Python libraries on Windows can be challenging.

This message [indicates that the Visual C++ compiler cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat):

> Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

You could install [Visual Studio Express](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) and try again, or use another compiler as suggested in the referenced question. But you may find that this leads to further problems, e.g. now the MySQL headers can't be found.

Manually installing MySQL from source will likely fix that issue, but that might reveal its own dependency problems.

Instead of going through this rigmarole you might consider installing [precompiled versions from Christoph Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Comment: @nivhanin, that's a different driver but it should work. The page I referenced in my answer contains many useful Python libraries, not just a MySQL driver.